# R snippet to Python

Tags: python, r, python-2.7

I would appreciate if someone could provide support in translating this for loop written in R to Python:

```
iGs<-c()
for (B in 602:6000)
{
  iG3=(2*iG2)-iG1
  iGs[B-602+1]<-c(iG3)
  iG1=iG2
  iG2=iG3
}
```

assuming that `iG1=45` and `iG2=46` (ie. single values). As I understand it (newbie in Python here), it should be something like this:

```
B = range(602,6001,1)
iG3 = (2*iG2)-iG1
iGs = [???]
```

where `iGs` is the final list of values (?) after iterating from 602 to 6000, and also after concatenating those values corresponding to 600 and 601 that were previously calculated (ie. `iG1` and `iG2`).

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: yes, forgot to mention it, they are single values

Comment: What is `c`?  How is `iGs` initialized?

Comment: You can just do `iGs = [];for b in range(602,6001,1):
    iG3 = (2*iG2)-iG1;
    iGs.append(iG3);
    iG1=iG2;
    iG2=iG3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could initialize a `list` in `Python`

```
iGs = []
```

and `append`

```
for b in range(602,6001,1):
    iG3 = (2*iG2)-iG1
    iGs.append(iG3)
    iG1=iG2
    iG2=iG3
```

-checking the output

```
len(iGs)
#5399

iGs[-5:len(iGs)]
#[5441, 5442, 5443, 5444, 5445]
iGs[0:5]
#[47, 48, 49, 50, 51]
```

Comparing with `R`

```
length(iGs)
#[1] 5399

head(iGs)
#[1] 47 48 49 50 51 52

tail(iGs)
#[1] 5440 5441 5442 5443 5444 5445
```